# CSS only slidedown on checkbox check

Tags: css

I'm looking to create a slidedown effect on checkbox check without JS, so pure css. The problem is we can't use JS on this page.

I've look on so many websites, but they all say something different and most do use JS.

My HTML:

```
<label>
 <input class="open-content" type="checkbox">
  <div class="label-container">
   <div style="color: #EC008C; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700;">Open this tab</div>
   <div style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: 700;">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-open fade-new">Show this content with slidedown</div>
</label>
```

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.open-content:checked ~ .content-open {
 visibility: visible!important; max-height: none!important;
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.fade-new { 
 transition: visbility 0.3s ease-in-out, max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content-open {
 max-height: 0px;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
</style>
```

And how it looks:
[image]

But it isn't animated. I used opacity 0 to 1 and that works to make a nice animation, but I prefer sliding down if that is possible with checkbox + pure CSS. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You have a `</span>` in your markup which doesn't belong.

Comment: In your stylesheet, in the style declaration for `.fade-new` you reference the property `visbility`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a pure CSS slide-down using the **checkbox hack**.

In this example I have separated the `<label>` from the `<input>` and linked them by:

- giving the `<input>` an `id`
- giving the `<label>` a matching `for` attribute

**Working Example (Version 1):**

This version slides down.

```css
.open-content {
 display: none;
}

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #EC008C;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-text::after {
  content: '+';
  display: inline;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 6;
 padding: 6px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: translateY(-50px);
 transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.open-content:checked ~ .content {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<input id="open-content" class="open-content" type="checkbox">

<label class="label-text" for="open-content">
Open this tab
</label>

<div class="content">
<p>Show this content with slidedown</p>
</div>
```

---

**Working Example (Version 2):**

This version unfurls.

```css
.open-content {
 display: none;
}

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 12;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #EC008C;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-text::after {
  content: '+';
  display: inline;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 6;
 padding: 6px;
 height: 0;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 0.6s linear;
}

.open-content:checked ~ .content {
 opacity: 1;
 height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<input id="open-content" class="open-content" type="checkbox">

<label class="label-text" for="open-content">
Open this tab
</label>

<div class="content">
<p>Show this content with slidedown</p>
<p>Show this content with slidedown</p>
<p>Show this content with slidedown</p>
</div>
```

---

### Further Reading:

- [The "Checkbox Hack" (and things you can do with it) - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Comment: Hi! This seems to work really nice. Only problem is it doesn't hide the box when it isn't checked. And the height of the box is always flexible. There will come another container under it.

Comment: Fixed it with setting max-height to 0 and then max-height: none!important. Everything works now, thanks!

Comment: I've adjusted it so that the `.content` unfurls rather than simply sliding down. Note that you will encounter an issue with transitioning from `height: 0` to `height: auto` - that's beyond the capabilities of CSS. If you want to unfurl, rather than slide down, you _must_ declare an explicit height for your unfurled `.content`.

Comment: You probably don't need to use `!important` - that's a "cheat mode" for when you're debugging.

Comment: Ah right it also works without !important. I mainly do e-mail development so that's why... But your initial approach works with using max-height: 0 and then max-height: none. So there was no need to change your answer :-) Thanks!

Comment: I've reincluded the first version for the sake of completeness. Thank you for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it help you

you also can use  [css animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
.fade-new{
height:0;
background:red;
opacity:0;
transition:1s;
}

.open-content:checked ~ .fade-new{
height:300px;
opacity:1;
transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<label>
 <input class="open-content" type="checkbox">
  <div class="label-container">
   <div style="color: #EC008C; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700;">Open this tab</div>
   <div style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: 700;">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-open fade-new">Show this content with slidedown</div></span>
</label>
```